# StaleObjectStateException on one domain object in a list affects all remaining updates

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Quartz job in Grails that iterates my users and do a nightly update on each user. However, if I get a StaleObjectStateException on an update of a user object, it seems every update after that gets the same StaleObjectStateException. Something like this:

```
def users = User.list()
users.each { user ->
  try {
    user.doUpdate()
    user.save()
  } catch (all) {
    // I end up here for every user object after a StaleObjectStateException
  }
}
```

How can I recover? I don't mind sporadic failures (ideally I collect these and try again at the end), but now this literally stops all remaining updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be doing each update/save in a new transaction, otherwise any failures will effect the entire transaction / hibernate session. This makes better sense since each update/save should be it's own atomic operation anyway.

You should also get each domain object inside the transaction.

```
def userIds = User.withCriteria {
  projections {
    property("id")
  }
}
userIds.each { userId ->
    User.withTransaction {
      try {
        def user = User.get(userId)
        user.doUpdate()
        user.save()
      } catch (all) {
        // do whatever.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! It works without the flush, so I will leave that out to not slow down an already time-consuming operation. The transaction seems to have no effect on the performance.

Comment: The flush shouldn't be there except for rare cases when you depend on something happening at the database _now_, e.g. a trigger. The Spring/Hibernate transaction manager always flushes before committing. I'd also move the body of the `withTransaction` block to a transactional service method.

Comment: Removed the `flush` and I agree, it should be in a proper service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too early to shout ok. The exception now seems to happen at the withTransaction level, so it was never catched. I then put the withTransaction in the try-catch, but that takes me back to the trailing StaleObjectStateExceptions. Moving it to a service made no difference, nor did flush and clear on the current Hibernate session in the catch block. I have also tried withNewSession with no difference. Any other ideas that might help? I'm really stuck and as the phrase goes: "it should be simple" ;-)

Comment: My catch is empty. I have edited your answer according to my conclusions, which are that Hibernate must be treating my user objects as invalid if they are fetched outside the transaction and hence "nothing works" after that. It works if I get them in the transaction, it will probably be a slower operation and that might be another showstopper since it already takes almost 4 hours during the night. But that is another problem and possibly another question. Thanks for your assistance!