# Object in for loop not saving

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a little batch upload job where I'm iterating throw a CSV file and creating objects and saving them using grails gorm. If a record in the csv file has any failures, I skip the record and move on to the next. I'm finding I'm unable to get any of my objects to save without wrapping my save in a new transaction using withNewTransaction. I'm assuming this is a hack to solving the real problem. I'm wondering if anybody would be able to help me to understand what is happening here.

controller

```
def uploadFile() {      
    def division = params.division;

    userService.requireRole(division)

    MultipartFile file = request.getFile('file');

    if(file.empty) {
        flash.message = "File cannot be empty"          
    } else {
        def effortDetailMap = batchUploadService.processBatch(file, division);                  

        flash.success = effortDetailMap['Success'].size() + " new records were successfully added.";
        flash.failed = effortDetailMap['Failed'].size() + " records failed to be added.";
        flash.filtered = effortDetailMap['Filtered'].size() + " records were filtered.";

        batchUploadService.excelOutput(effortDetailMap);            
    }
    redirect (action:'upload', params: [division: params.division])
}
```

BatchUploadService

```
def populateBean(file) {
    CsvToBean<EffortDetail> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();

    Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    columnMapping.put("ITEM_NO", "alternateId");
    columnMapping.put("FIRST_NAME", "firstName");
    columnMapping.put("LAST_NAME", "lastName");
    columnMapping.put("TASK_CODE", "orgkey");
    columnMapping.put("PAY_END_DATE", "expenseDate");
    columnMapping.put("TOT_TDS_TIME", "projectHours");
    columnMapping.put("411 TOTAL", "totalHours");

    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<EffortDetail> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<EffortDetail>();
    strategy.setType(EffortDetail.class);
    strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());

    CustomReader csvReader = new CustomReader(reader, (char) '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

    return csvToBean.parse(strategy, csvReader);
}

def processBatch(file, division) {
    def effortDetails = populateBean(file)

    def effortDetailMap = [:]
    effortDetailMap["Success"] = []
    effortDetailMap["Failed"] = []
    effortDetailMap["Filtered"] = []

    for (def effortDetail in effortDetails) {
        String orgKey = effortDetail.getOrgkey();

        if (orgKey.matches("\\d{6}") || orgKey.matches("\\d{6} HRI")) {
            effortDetail.setOrgkey(orgKey.substring(0, 6));
        } else {
            effortDetailMap['Filtered'] << effortDetail;
            continue;
        }

        effortDetail.setDivision(division)
        effortDetail.setPkDivision(effortDetail.getDivision());
        effortDetail.setPkOrgkey(effortDetail.getOrgkey());

        try {
            if(effortDetail.getTotalHours() == null || effortDetail.getTotalHours().isEmpty()) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Invalid Total Hours");
            } else if(new BigDecimal(effortDetail.getTotalHours()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(75)) < 0) {
                effortDetail.setTotalHours("75");
            }

            if(effortDetail.getProjectHours() == null || effortDetail.getProjectHours().isEmpty()) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Invalid Project Hours");
            }

            RecoveryDetail recoveryDetail = recoveryDetailService.fill(effortDetail);

            if(!recoveryDetail.validate()) {
                def errors = new StringBuilder()

                recoveryDetail.errors.each {errors.append(it)}

                throw new Exception(errors);
            }

            RecoveryDetail.withNewTransaction {TransactionStatus status ->
                try {
                  recoveryDetail.save(failOnError: true)
                } catch (ex) {
                  status.setRollbackOnly()
                }
            }

            effortDetailMap['Success'] << effortDetail
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            effortDetail.failure = ex.message;
            effortDetailMap['Failed'] << effortDetail
        }
    }

    return effortDetailMap
}
```

RecoveryDetailService

```
def fill(params) {
    def division = params.pkDivision.trim(),
        peid = params.pkPeid != null ? params.pkPeid.trim() : null,
        alternateId = params.alternateId != null ? params.alternateId.trim() : null,
        orgkey = params.pkOrgkey != null ? params.pkOrgkey.trim() : null

    Date expenseDate = new SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(params.expenseDate.trim());

    List<RecoverySetup> recoverySetups = RecoverySetup.createCriteria().list{
        createAlias("oneSolOrgkey", "oneSolOrgkey")
        eq("division", division)
        eqProperty("oneSolOrgkey.orgkey", "orgkey")
        eqProperty("oneSolOrgkey.division", "division")
        or {
            eq("peid", peid)
            eq("alternateId", alternateId)
        }
        eq("status", Status.AC)
        le("oneSolOrgkey.startDate", expenseDate)
        ge("oneSolOrgkey.endDate", expenseDate)
        like("oneSolOrgkey.orgkey", orgkey.trim() + '%')
    }

    def recoverySetupInstance = null;

    if(recoverySetups.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NullPointerException("No recovery setup records were found with " + (peid != null ? "peid " + peid : "alternate id " +  alternateId) + " and orgkey " + orgkey);
    } else if(recoverySetups.size() > 1) {
        throw new NullPointerException("More than one recovery setup record was found with " + (peid != null ? "peid " + peid : "alternate id " +  alternateId) + " and orgkey " + orgkey);
    }

    recoverySetupInstance = recoverySetups.get(0);

    def recoveryDetailInstance = new RecoveryDetail(params);

    recoveryDetailInstance.setDivision(recoverySetupInstance.getDivision().trim());
    recoveryDetailInstance.setOrgkey(recoverySetupInstance.getOrgkey().trim());
    recoveryDetailInstance.setPeid(recoverySetupInstance.getPeid().trim());
    recoveryDetailInstance.setRecoverySetup(recoverySetupInstance);
    recoveryDetailInstance.setExpenseDate(expenseDate);
    recoveryDetailInstance.setAdjustmentNumber(currentAdjustmentNumber(recoverySetupInstance, expenseDate));
    calculateExpense(recoveryDetailInstance, params);

    return recoveryDetailInstance;
}
```

Comment: Your problems sound very similar to what I experienced during a batch job a while ago. Take a close look at this thread, especially the comments that led up to the final answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878087/staleobjectstateexception-on-one-domain-object-in-a-list-affects-all-remaining-u

Comment: So are you getting any exception inside your catch block?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal which catch block are you referring to?

Comment: Try to indicate your service as non transactional: static transactional = false. It may be your problem